# Resolving exports from of index.ts published to NPM?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, stackblitz

I have [this package](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice) with an  index.ts file.

The corresponding `index.d.ts` file that is installed under `node_modules/@fireflysemantics/slice` looks like this:

```
export { EStore } from './EStore';
export { Slice } from './Slice';
export { OStore } from './OStore';
export * from './types';
```

The corresponding `index.js` looks like this:

```
"use strict";
function __export(m) {
    for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
}
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var EStore_1 = require("./EStore");
exports.EStore = EStore_1.EStore;
var Slice_1 = require("./Slice");
exports.Slice = Slice_1.Slice;
var OStore_1 = require("./OStore");
exports.OStore = OStore_1.OStore;
__export(require("./types"));
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

When I try to import the `OStore` using Stackblitz it will not resolve as a root import.  For example this work:

```
import {OStore} from '@fireflysemantics/slice/OStore';
```

But this does not:

```
import {OStore} from '@fireflysemantics/slice/';
```

Here's a stackblitz link in case that's helpful:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vj1vpa

The stackblitz error is:

> Can't find module:
>   @fireflysemantics/slice/index.ts (@6.4.2)  Check your import statements & ensure you're importing the correct module names.

Should `index.ts` be copied to the distribution folder before installing to NPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a folder like you are doing with:

```
import {OStore} from '@fireflysemantics/slice/';
```

It will try to import the index.ts file in that folder. Hence, the error if its not a module or it does not exist.